# Server unresponsive when restart network

Tags: linux, debian

We have a debian 11 just installed and when i execute "systemctl restart networking" the server becomes unresponsive and the console shows this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP8P3.png)

I have to restart from vcenter console. what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided i can substract an ideea that the temporary configuration is not good.
Do attach some addition information, please.

Comment: Tell me what do you need please. Im not a linux expert.